# how to show suggestion input values users previously typed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show suggestions below the input field. i mean if we enter name in input field the suggestion should show Name should not exceed 15 characters and once i enter the value the suggestion should get disappear. Can anyone please help me in this query?

for example

users enter one data to update his address..another users enter if type same area in address..it should be in suggestion below

First Name

```
                    <div class="md-form w-50 ml-4 deliverycontact_lastname">
                        <input value="" name="deliveryContact_lastName" type="text" id="deliveryContact_lastName" class="form-control" disabled="true">
                        <label class="office_form-datas" for="deliveryContact_lastName">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant information, like Html,css jquery

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?  Creating the HTML structure?  Showing/hiding a dom element on focus/blur/change?  Checking length of input?

Comment: Where will you get the list of "suggestions"? Is it a static list? Is it stored somewhere?

Comment: is it static..is any option to store browser storage and get back..same data typed again..show suggestion